# VS + Win32 + C++ + PNG

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, png

I have added a png as a resource in the resource editor but how to load and display? I would like to display it in a picture control or owner draw. I don't want to have an external file floating around. I think I remember reading somewhere that you can "bind" files to the executable but basically still refer to them as if they were external files?

(creating a simple gui like interface with a few background and some button states... but only want one exe, not an exe + button1.png + button2.png, etc. I need transparency feature too so no BMP. I also would like to keep it all within windows(no libpng, etc...))

Comment: You're right that there's a protocol for accessing resources as files. It's the [`res` protocol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767740%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It's nice for accessing a resource from script language. Working in C++ you don't need that. Just load the resource.

Comment: You can get transparency with bitmaps, too. Just not alpha transparency. If you need alpha transparency, PNG's are the way to go. Is that what you need?

Comment: The top 4 Google answers for "win32 png" all point back to Stack Overflow so that can't be your problem. Most answers start by reassuring that PNG support is in the WinAPIs, and in fact has been so for more than a decennium. So is your question how to load a resource? That is boilerplate code as well.

Comment: @Jongware: Loading a PNG from a resource is anything but boilerplate. You have to find the resource, lock it, load it, and extract it using the [WIC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719902.aspx). Do you have anything useful to contribute?

Comment: @IInspectable Yes, I would like alpha. Not absolutely necessary now but will be in the future. I've seen the tut about tricking windows by loading an png as an icon but I can't seem to do it in VS2015, which seems different than what is described by the article. I don't want any unnecessary dependencies but possibly GDI+. Basically I want a simple, hopefully premade solution. Remember than it should be able to load the the png from the resource file(.rc or res or whatever).

Comment: a HINT: RC_DATA, SHCreateMemStream ( or CreateStreamOnHGlobal),  IImgCtx interface, IStream Interface. THATS ALL.

Answer (score 0):

This is a code I used to load a PNG resource to render it with Direct2D (but it doesn't restrict you with PNG format only or with D2D only):

```
/**
 * Loads image from the specified resource and creates Direct2D bitmap object for that image.
 *
 * Parameters:
 * >pszResourceName
 * Image resource name.
 * >pszResourceType
 * Image resource type.
 * >pImagingFactory
 * Pointer to an instance of IWICImagingFactory object.
 * >ppBitmapSource
 * Receives loaded bitmap.
 *
 * Returns:
 * Standard HRESULT code.
 */
HRESULT directx_toolkit::loadBitmapFromResource(
    _In_z_ LPCTSTR pszResourceName,
    _In_z_ LPCTSTR pszResourceType,
    _In_ IWICImagingFactory* pImagingFactory,
    _COM_Outptr_result_maybenull_ IWICFormatConverter** ppBitmapSource) const
{
    ATLADD com_ptr<IWICFormatConverter> converter {};
    HRESULT hr = E_FAIL;
    HRSRC hResource = FindResource(ATL::_AtlBaseModule.GetResourceInstance(), pszResourceName, pszResourceType);
    if (nullptr != hResource)
    {
        HGLOBAL hData = LoadResource(ATL::_AtlBaseModule.GetResourceInstance(), hResource);
        if (nullptr != hData)
        {
            void* pData = LockResource(hData);
            DWORD nSize = SizeofResource(ATL::_AtlBaseModule.GetResourceInstance(), hResource);
            if (pData && nSize)
            {
                // Create a WIC stream to map onto the memory.
                ATLADD com_ptr<IWICStream> stream {};
                hr = pImagingFactory->CreateStream(stream.getAddressOf());
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    hr = stream->InitializeFromMemory(reinterpret_cast<BYTE*> (pData), nSize);
                    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                    {
                        // Prepare decoder for the stream, the first image frame and conveter (to change image color
                        // format).
                        ATLADD com_ptr<IWICBitmapDecoder> decoder {};
                        hr = pImagingFactory->CreateDecoderFromStream(
                            stream.get(), nullptr, WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnLoad, decoder.getAddressOf());
                        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                        {
                            ATLADD com_ptr<IWICBitmapFrameDecode> frame {};
                            hr = decoder->GetFrame(0, frame.getAddressOf());
                            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                            {
                                hr = pImagingFactory->CreateFormatConverter(converter.getAddressOf());
                                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                                {
                                    hr = converter->Initialize(
                                        frame.get(),
                                        GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPBGRA,
                                        WICBitmapDitherTypeNone,
                                        nullptr,
                                        0,
                                        WICBitmapPaletteTypeMedianCut);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
    }
    *ppBitmapSource = SUCCEEDED(hr) ? converter.detach() : nullptr;
    return hr;
}


/**
 * Loads image from the specified resource and creates Direct2D bitmap object for that image.
 *
 * Parameters:
 * >pszResourceName
 * Image resource name.
 * >pszResourceType
 * Image resource type.
 * >pImagingFactory
 * Pointer to an instance of IWICImagingFactory object.
 * >pDC
 * Direct2D context.
 * >ppBitmap
 * Receives loaded bitmap.
 *
 * Returns:
 * Standard HRESULT code.
 *
 * Remarks:
 * Since 'ID2D1DeviceContext::CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap' can't be called simultaneously from multiple threads, caller
 * should synchronize access to the 'pDC'.
 */
HRESULT directx_toolkit::loadBitmapFromResource(
    _In_z_ LPCTSTR pszResourceName,
    _In_z_ LPCTSTR pszResourceType,
    _In_ IWICImagingFactory* pImagingFactory,
    _In_ ID2D1DeviceContext* pDC,
    _COM_Outptr_result_maybenull_ ID2D1Bitmap1** ppBitmap) const
{
    ATLADD com_ptr<ID2D1Bitmap1> bitmap {};
    ATLADD com_ptr<IWICFormatConverter> converter {};
    HRESULT hr = loadBitmapFromResource(pszResourceName, pszResourceType, pImagingFactory, converter.getAddressOf());
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pDC->CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap(converter.get(), bitmap.getAddressOf());
    }
    *ppBitmap = SUCCEEDED(hr) ? bitmap.detach() : nullptr;
    return hr;
}
```

(`ATLADD com_ptr` is my analogue of `ATL::CComPtr`)

And there's no doubt -- you can use **32bpp BMP** to get a resource with transparency mask.

Comment: Surely there is an easier way? While I like the idea of using DirectX, it adds several dependencies that I don't really want at this point. I guess I'll just go with bmp.

Comment: @AbstractDissonance I didn't try to force you to use DirectX at all :-D I just showed how you CAN handle PNG resources with WIC. And that's all. But I didn't restrict you with a particular rendering engine.

Comment: @AbstractDissonance: Unless you are fine with taking a dependency on ATL (and GDI+) by using [CImage::Load](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tf4bytf8.aspx), you will have to use WIC one way or another. I don't understand what you mean by *"easier way"*. This answer is not ideal in that it mixes a lot of unrelated stuff all of this (no need for a DirectX namespace, for example, or the use of yet another undisclosed custom smart pointer implementation).